# fscanf segmentation fault, trying to read a file and put values in an array - c

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf, eof

my friend is studying for an exam. He keeps receiving the segmentation fault on " while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo) != EOF)".
How can I help him?

You can find his code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DIM 100
typedef struct
{
    char costruttore[20];
    int ns;
    int costo;
} memoria;

void lettura(memoria A[], int *n)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("memory.txt", "r");
    if( f == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s: %s\n", "memory.txt", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
    while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo) != EOF)
        i++;
    (*n) = i;
    fclose(f);
    for (i = 0; i < (*n); i++)
        printf("%s %d %d\n", A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo);
}

int main()
{
    memoria A[DIM];
    int n;
    lettura(A, &n);
    return 0;
}
```

memory.txt content

```
PerKele 56 41
AM-Silicon 49 41
JKR 33 50
Atlantic 57 62
JADA 50 50
JKR 40 51
Drast 28 35
SGUZ 73 55
JADA 29 46
FARSTIC 65 30
Drast 41 36
FRoW 48 67
FARSTIC 39 62
Drast 27 44
SGUZ 51 50
Drast 58 60
Liquid 41 71
SWP3 50 63
KRRAM 54 24
YTK 32 60
ALOE 37 57
HAL 53 39
AM-Silicon 59 50
Atlantic 24 42
ALOE 31 46
JADA 38 65
Nikit 48 49
PerKele 68 37
HAL 46 53
TOO 73 60
HAL 31 37
YTK 39 55
Nikit 57 47
FARSTIC 40 47
AM-Silicon 68 52
HAL 50 50
JADA 32 37
FRoW 47 53
SWP3 50 50
FRoW 52 52
JADA 63 58
Liquid 47 46
Drast 36 54
ALOE 44 30
HAL 39 33
Drast 48 41
SWP3 52 56
KRRAM 65 56
```

He tried to put the & in "A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo" but it didn't work.

Comment: he forgot the `&` in `while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", &A[i].costruttore, &A[i].ns, &A[i].costo) != EOF)`

Comment: I personally don't like/use/know the `scanf` family of functions, but I believe you want `while (fscanf(...) == 3)` for your loop condtion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky would they still want the `&` on the `costruttore` arg?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why the `&` operator on the string member?

Comment: @Jason yes, the `&` is mandatory

Comment: @Jabberwocky nops, is an array: `char costruttore[20];`, it decays into a pointer when passed, you don't need the `&`

Comment: @DavidRanieri According to the example on the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf), Jabberwocky is correct.  I wonder why that is?  Is there a case where the pointer would be modified? (yet another reason to avoid these `scanf` functions.)

Comment: @Jason Interesting. Looks like a buggy man page to me.

Comment: @Jason `"%s"` in `fscanf` is expecting a `char *`, not a `char(*)[20]`

Comment: The man page says _"Since version 2.7, glibc also provides the m modifier . . . It is specified in the POSIX.1-2008 standard."_ This modifier is not part of the C standard and is not used in the OP. So there should be _no_  & on the costruttore arg. The man page shows a correct example for the glibc extension of the m modifier that is not part of standard C.

Comment: @Jason The only code example at https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf uses `%m`, not `%s`: `n = scanf("%m[a-z]", &p);`  `%m` is a [POSIX extension](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html): "An optional assignment-allocation character 'm'"

Comment: (cont) "The %c, %s, and %[ conversion specifiers shall accept an optional assignment-allocation character 'm', which shall cause a memory buffer to be allocated to hold the string converted including a terminating null character. In such a case, the argument corresponding to the conversion specifier should be a reference to a pointer variable that will receive a pointer to the allocated buffer."

Comment: @AviBerger it has an ambiguous wording though: "*..the next pointer must be a pointer to character array..*" as opposed to the standard wording "*..argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array..*".

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't see that there is much of an ambiguity here. The phrasing is parallel to and much the same as used for other specifiers. It does not say "pointer to pointer" which is what would be needed to support the debated (mis)use of "&".

Comment: @AndrewHenle Doh, sorry. I think I was mixing up that `fscanf` with the `printf`. This is why I don't comment on `scanf` questions =]

Comment: @AviBerger `&a` will be a pointer to `char` array considering `char a[20];`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK. you have a point.

Comment: @DavidRanieri sorry yes, you're right, `A[i].costruttore` being already a pointer (decayed from an array), the `&` is not needed

Answer (score 2):

**Save time, enable all compiler warnings**

This is the #1 lesson here.

**`"%d"` matches a `int *`, not an `int` in `fscanf()`**

Use the address of an `int`.

```
// fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo)
fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, &A[i].ns, &A[i].costo)
```

**Do not use `"%s"` without a *width***

Use a width 1 less than the array count.

```
char costruttore[20];
...
// fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, ...
fscanf(f, "%19s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, ...
```

**Do not compare against `EOF`**

`fscanf(f, "%s %d %d"...` can return `EOF, 1, 2, 3` (and *maybe* 0).  Rather than test against 1 undesirable value compare against the desired result.

```
// while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo) != EOF)
while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", A[i].costruttore, A[i].ns, A[i].costo) == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jabberwocky noted, pointers are needed within the fscanf, however these are only needed for the `costo` and `ns` fields.

Here's an equivalent example of OPs code, with the correct structure:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 100

typedef struct record {
    char f0[20];
    int f1, f2;
} record_t;

int main (void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("memory.txt", "r");
    record_t records[DIM];

    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", records[i].f0, &records[i].f1, &records[i].f2) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

This runs, and produces the correct results. Without the `&` in front of `f1` and `f2`, it will segfault.

Comment: "however these are only needed for the costo and ns fields." --> Not quite.  Pointers are needed for `"%s"` too.  Note; that `records[i].f0` is correct and is a _pointer_ when passed as a function argument, even without a `&`.

Comment: Thank you, no more segmentation fault. But now the problem is that the code doesn't work.